# DateTime Parsing from string for Yahoo Finance

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, yahoo-finance

I am very sorry to bother but I am new to Python3...

I am trying to parse HTML table to get a list of tickers and dates for which I would like to then populate stock prices from yahoo...

I have a cell in which there is a text and then a date in a following format: April 20, 2020 ... I would like to extract just the date so I can use it in Yahoo API after but I am getting errors with the following code

```
date=result.find("td", attrs {'class':'column5'}).text.replace('\n',' ')
date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Many thanks for any guidance!

Comment: your code seems perfectly fine to me, what is the error you get (full traceback)?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 32, in <module>
    date=datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: Seems like you input string `date` doesn't exactly look like e.g. `April 20, 2020`. Could you show what `print(date)` gives you? maybe there's a space/newline/tab etc. character trailing at the end.

Comment: April 20, 2020
April 3, 2020
March 18, 2020
February 29, 2020
March 29, 2019
March 19, 2019 
1) September 20, 2018 - IPO ~20% 2) March 8, 2019 - exchange offer complete
March 4, 2019
1) October 11, 2018 - IPO ~15% 2) March 1, 2019 - spinoff remaining stake
February 25, 2019

Comment: i think my problem is that there is text in some cells and that s maybe producing the traceback

Comment: jep, looks like you need to filter / separate the input string first, e.g. with some regex. then, you can pass each string that matches the format, like "2020 March 18", to `datetime.strptime`.

Comment: np, made a little example, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an illustration of my comment, use `regex` to find all substrings matching the datetime format `'%B %d, %Y'`and then convert the format as desired:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

s = "April 20, 2020 April 3, 2020 March 18, 2020 February 29, 2020 March 29, 2019 March 19, 2019 1) September 20, 2018 - IPO ~20% 2) March 8, 2019 - exchange offer complete March 4, 2019 1) October 11, 2018 - IPO ~15% 2) March 1, 2019 - spinoff remaining stake February 25, 2019"

dates = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+\ [0-9]{1,2},\ [0-9]{4}', s)
# ['April 20, 2020',
#  'April 3, 2020',
#  'March 18, 2020',
#  'February 29, 2020',
#  'March 29, 2019',
#  'March 19, 2019',
#  'September 20, 2018',
#  'March 8, 2019',
#  'March 4, 2019',
#  'October 11, 2018',
#  'March 1, 2019',
#  'February 25, 2019']

for d in dates:
    print(datetime.strptime(d,'%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
# 2020-04-20
# 2020-04-03
# 2020-03-18
# 2020-02-29
# 2019-03-29
# 2019-03-19
# 2018-09-20
# 2019-03-08
# 2019-03-04
# 2018-10-11
# 2019-03-01
# 2019-02-25
```

Comment: I intergrated your code to mine and still getting a traceback

Comment: 'for result in results:
    date=result.find("td", attrs={'class':'column-5'}).text.replace('\n',' ')
    date=re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+\ [0-9]{1,2},\ [0-9]{4}', date)
    date =datetime.strptime(date,'%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: The traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 34, in <module>
    date =datetime.strptime(date,'%B %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list

Comment: @Tomas: in your case, `date` is a `list`. you have to pass the elements from the list to `datetime.strptime` one by one, as I show in `for d in dates: print(...`.